# golang template string in javascrip function param error

Tags: javascript, html, go

quick question. I am using golang templates and I am trying to pass a golang string as a param to a javascript function.

`onclick="Pressed('{{.Country.CountryName}}', this)"`

I tried a couple of different approaches such as:

```
onclick="PressedLetter(\"{{.Country.CountryName}}\", this)"
onclick="PressedLetter('"+{{.Country.CountryName}}+"', this)"
onclick="PressedLetter({{.Country.CountryName}}, this)"
```

all of the above approaches breaks my html and gives me a blank screen.

when I do the following line, it works flawlessly.
`onclick="PressedLetter('usa', this)"`

my java script method being called:
`function PressedLetter(country, x)`

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong ? pls ?
thks in advanced

Comment: What is .Country.CountryName? May be Country.CountryName without first dot?

Comment: Hi as far as I understand, golang template the first dot gets the variable in the current context. using without the dot wont compile

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code as shown below. `{{.Country.CountryName}}` should be wrapped with single quotes.

```js
onclick="PressedLetter('{{.Country.CountryName}}',this)"
```

**Here is the sample code**

- `main.go` file.

```golang
// Package main contains answer for 75785841.
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Country struct {
    CountryName string
}

type Data  struct {
    Title string
    ParsingValue string
    Country Country
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", r)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil))
}

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("home.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    data := Data {
        Title: "Sample `OnClick` function",
        ParsingValue: "123",
        Country: Country{
            CountryName: "Sri Lanka",
        },
    }

    err = t.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

- `home.html` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
    <script>
    function PressedLetter(name, value) {
        console.log(name,value)
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
    <button type="submit" onclick="PressedLetter('{{.Country.CountryName}}',this)">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: In above example, `main.go` file and `home.html` file should be in a same directory.